# I can't interact with the UI after Blender crashes

Tags: interface

```
Windows 10
Blender 3.1
```

I'm having quite a weird problem - Blender crashes > It comes back > The UI frezes and I can't use Blender again unless I force quit it - The program keeps running normally, but it's like there is a screenshot of the program preventing me from seeing what's happening. Is there a way to fix it?

Here's a video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIJta.jpg

Comment: Could require a reinstall. Does this always happen with Blender or is it just this file? Have you tested this on a blank/very empty file?

Comment: Yes, this is happening pretty much everytime it crashes with any given file.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest a reinstall. If that doesn't work, it may be your PC but Blender isn't particularly resource-heavy.

Comment: @Onyx I've reinstalled blender (I even used Iobit Uninstaller for removing residual files) and I'm still facing the same problem.